# iPhone restrict to a certain version

Tags: iphone, app-store

I want my app to download only on iPhone 5 and higher. I don't want it to be possible to download on iPhone 4S or lower. How can I achieve this?

Comment: It's easier to target the iOS version number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't restrict your app by device, but you can target specific hardware features by adding them to your info.plist.

The key you're looking for is called [`UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1397/_index.html).

[image: Xcode and required device capabilities.]

Here are the valid keys, taken from [this list](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=09132010a) at Apple's developer website: `telephony`, `wifi`, `sms`, `still-camera`, `auto-focus-camera`, `front-facing-camera`, `camera-flash`, `video-camera`, `gyroscope`, `location-services`, `magnetometer`, `gamekit`, `opengles-1`, `microphone`, `opengles-2`, `armv6`, `armv7`, `peer-peer`, and `bluetooth-le`.

Some keys will approximate (such as `armv6` and `armv7`) what you want. If you require `bluetooth-le`, you'll cut out a slew of older devices. The gyroscope was introduced with the iPhone 4. The `camera-flash` key cuts out iPad and iPod touch models without flash.

Using these keys, think about who you're cutting out, but be sure that you're doing it for the right reasons. Excluding a demographic of your potential user base is risky and puts you at a disadvantage in an already competitive market.

Oh, and I'd strongly caution against using these as a shortcut to optimizing against older devices. Performance is your killer feature. Don't blow it.

<sub>*UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities [was featured](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=09132010a) on Apple's iOS developer website in September 2010.</sub>

Comment: That's what I thought... Do you know what specific hardware features can I use to restrict app for iPhone 5? For iPhone 4 it would be front camera I guess...

Comment: If you're looking for performance requirements, I'd go with the `opengles-2` key, since support was added with the either the iPhone 4 or 4S. (I'm not sure.) That being said, using a feature to limit your app is dangerous, because I'm not sure if you can change it in a later binary.)

Comment: yeah, my issue is performance, my app is not running good enough in iPhone 4, but it's ok on 5, I wanted to publish it now, and then think about optimizing for iPhone 4...

Comment: What sort of performance issues? I'd suggest profiling and posting another question here on Stack Overflow before resorting to this.

Comment: My app is capturing pictures from camera, when I run it on iPhone 4 sometime it crashes or stop capturing pictures. On iPhone 5 it works always good. Thanks for your suggestions, I guess I have to read more about profiling.